# Flashing stock firmware deletes everything from / (root) directory?

Tags: xiaomi

Hello i have a Xiaomi Mi 8 and i was playing with adb shell servies commands and now it shows "android phone service stop working" and it keeps rebooting.My question is when i flashing stock firmware from xiaomi tool, deletes everything from / (root) directory and installs new one folders/files?I want to check this to make sure if it's hardware or software problem

Answer (score 0):

"when i flashing stock firmware from xiaomi tool, deletes everything from / (root) directory and installs new one folders/files?" 
Most likely yes, if there is no option to keep them in Xiaomi tool. All internal storage will be cleaned except external SD card if you have inserted it.